# Apply condition between rows of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table where the first column is time, which increases by 1 second increments.
The second column brings the code that started the day in its first line. This could be any between 1-5. The 0 (zero) value indicates the code didn't change. When the code changes, it is indicated the time it changed and which number it changed to (thus, Event), but for as long as it stays the same it will be shown 0 (zero) again.

[image]

My intent is to make a new column specifying the present code at any time. So far, I have been doing this in Excel, with the following conditions and results:

[image]     [image]

Is there a way for this Excel condition to be applied in a query to create this new column?
I've been testing CASE WHEN statements, and I tried to implement Lag or Lead functions in it. But so far none of them worked to apply the same value of the previous row when the event is 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `event` is always increasing, you can use a window `max()`:

```
select time, event, max(event) over(order by time) code
from mytable
```

Else, it is a bit more complicated. One option is to build the groups with a window sum:

```
select time, event, max(event) over(partition by grp order by time) code
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(case when event > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by time) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: I have a slightly different situation. But your hint on using window sum to create proper partitions helps me get over the hurdle. Thanks a lot!